# Navigation bar using html and css is not clickable

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am creating a website and I wanted to create a navigation bar in CSS. However, the navigation bar is not clickable. This was made in HTML and CSS.

HTML code containing the navigation bar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<ul id=navlist><li class=active> Home </li>
<li> <a title="LINK: My Youtube videos” href="youtubevideosch9changes.html”> My Youtube videos </a> </li>
<li> <a title="LINK: My Flash games” href="gamesch9changes.html> My Flash games </a> </li>
<li> <a title="LINK: Rants and articles” href="Rantsandarticles.html”> Rants and articles </a> 


</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML Code with the End of this `"` Mark. You used the an opening double quote, instead of a closing one. Change `"LINK: My Youtube videos”` to `"LINK: My Youtube videos"`.

Use this following code,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<ul id=navlist><li class=active> Home </li>
<li> <a title="LINK: My Youtube videos" href="youtubevideosch9changes.html"> My Youtube videos </a> </li>
<li> <a title="LINK: My Flash games" href="gamesch9changes.html"> My Flash games </a> </li>
<li> <a title="LINK: Rants and articles" href="Rantsandarticles.html"> Rants and articles </a> 


</li>
</ul>
```